# FileNotFoundException while Unzip file

Tags: android

I am using following code to unzip the file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String zipFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();
    unpackZip(zipFilePath,"/MyRar.zip");
}
private boolean unpackZip(String path, String zipname)
{       
     InputStream is;
     ZipInputStream zis;
     try 
     {
         String filename;
         is = new FileInputStream(path + zipname);
         zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));          
         ZipEntry ze;
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int count;

         while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) 
         {
             // zapis do souboru
             filename = ze.getName();

             // Need to create directories if not exists, or
             // it will generate an Exception...
             if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                File fmd = new File(path + filename);
                fmd.mkdirs();
                continue;
             }

             FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

             // cteni zipu a zapis
             while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
             {
                 fout.write(buffer, 0, count);             
             }

             fout.close();               
             zis.closeEntry();
         }

         zis.close();
     } 
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     }

    return true;
}
}
```

Also I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in manifest file.

But it shows the file not found exception.

Logcat:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcardMyRar/list.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
at com.example.unzipfile.MainActivity.unpackZip(MainActivity.java:66)
at com.example.unzipfile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Comment: you missed a / ... (hint : `path + filename`)

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @halfer Okay, surely i'll consider in my upcoming threads... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now your directory is : `/mnt/sdcardMyRar/` check directory, it's incorrect !

check below suggestion :

```
String zipFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                       .getAbsolutePath() + "/";
```